# Get Size of Window when is Maximized in WPF

Tags: wpf, window, size, maximize-window

i search for a way to get the Width-Property of an Maximized WPF Window.

Any Ideas how can i get the absolute value?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualWidth}"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Just use the `ActualWidth` property.

Answer (score 6):

Use `ActualWidth`, instead of `Width`.

Answer (score 6):

[ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) will give you the width also in maximized state.